# Python get items in a list of that are not in a list

Tags: python

I have a list with countries: 
countries = `['United States', 'Canada', 'France', 'Japan', 'Turkey', 'Germany', 'Ghana', 'Hong Kong', 'United Kingdom']`

i want to get all the lines that do not contain any country.
this is my code:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()[1:5]
    a = [line.split(':') for line in lines]
    for country in countries:
        for line in a:
            if country not in line:
                print(line)
```

print(line) prints all the lines instead of printing those that do not contain countries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's what the [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) functions are for.

```
countries = ['United States', 'Canada', 'France', 'Japan', 'Turkey', 'Germany', 'Ghana', 'Hong Kong', 'United Kingdom']
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()[1:5]
    a = [line.split(':') for line in lines]
    for line in a:
        if not any(country in line for country in countries):
            print(line)
```

Comment: But with a set, you could simply say `countries.isdisjoint(line)`.

Comment: Yeah, `line` is not a line/string but a list - that might actually work, but possibly not how OP intended. We should see some sample lines and desired output for those lines to be sure...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
data = [i.strip('\n').split(":") for i in open('filename.txt')]
countries = ['United States', 'Canada', 'France', 'Japan', 'Turkey', 'Germany', 'Ghana', 'Hong Kong', 'United Kingdom']
final_data = [i for i in data if not any(b in countries for b in i)]
```